# How to insert tag conditionally into soap request body before calling endpoint?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to add tag to soap request body based on some condition

It should be added under the **ActionProperties** tag

so I tried to use the enrich mediator as follows :

```
<filter regex="false" source="get-property('IsValid')">
    <then>
    <enrich>
      <source clone="true" type="inline">
         <p857:Property propertyId="isArchived" settable="0" xsi:type="p857:SingletonString" 
           xmlns:p857="http://www.filenet.com/ns/fnce/2006/11/ws/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <p857:Value>1</p857:Value>
           </p857:Property>
      </source>
      <target 
      xmlns:p857="http://www.filenet.com/ns/fnce/2006/11/ws/schema" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      action="child" 
      type="custom" xpath="//p857:ExecuteChangesRequest/p857:ChangeRequest/p857:ActionProperties" />
   </enrich>
   </then>
        <else/>
   </filter>
    
    
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <soapenv:Header>
                    <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
                        <hd:UsernameToken xmlns:hd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
                            <hd:Username>$1</hd:Username>
                            <hd:Password>$2</hd:Password>
                        </hd:UsernameToken>
                    </Security>
                </soapenv:Header>
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <p857:ExecuteChangesRequest refresh="1" xmlns:p857="http://www.filenet.com/ns/fnce/2006/11/ws/schema">
                        <p857:ChangeRequest id="1" updateSequenceNumber="0">
                            <p857:TargetSpecification classId="ObjectStore" objectId="$3" serializationDuplicate="0"/>
                            <p857:Action autoUniqueContainmentName="1" classId="$4" defineSecurityParentage="0" xsi:type="p857:CreateAction"/>
                            <p857:Action autoClassify="0" checkinMinorVersion="0" xsi:type="p857:CheckinAction"/>
                            <p857:ActionProperties>

                                <p857:Property propertyId="DocumentTitle" settable="0" xsi:type="p857:SingletonString">
                                    <p857:Value>$5</p857:Value>
                                </p857:Property>
                                <p857:Property propertyId="ContentElements" settable="0" xsi:type="p857:ListOfObject">
                                    <p857:Value accessAllowed="0" classId="ContentTransfer" dependentAction="Insert" newIndex="0" originalIndex="0" serializationDuplicate="0" updateSequenceNumber="0">
                                        <p857:Property propertyId="ContentType" settable="0" xsi:type="p857:SingletonString">
                                            <p857:Value>$7</p857:Value>
                                        </p857:Property>
                                        <p857:Property propertyId="RetrievalName" settable="0" xsi:type="p857:SingletonString">
                                            <p857:Value>$5</p857:Value>
                                        </p857:Property>
                                        <p857:Property propertyId="Content" settable="0" xsi:type="p857:ContentData">
                                            <p857:Value xsi:type="p857:InlineContent">
                                                <p857:Binary>$6</p857:Binary>
                                            </p857:Value>
                                        </p857:Property>
                                    </p857:Value>
                                </p857:Property>
                            </p857:ActionProperties>
                            <p857:RefreshFilter levelDependents="0" maxElements="0" maxRecursion="0">
                                <p857:ExcludeProperties>DateCreated</p857:ExcludeProperties>
                                <p857:ExcludeProperties>DateLastModified</p857:ExcludeProperties>
                            </p857:RefreshFilter>
                        </p857:ChangeRequest>
                    </p857:ExecuteChangesRequest>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Username')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Password')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ObjectStore')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('DocumentClass')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('FileName')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('FileData')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ContentType')"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```

But I always get an error : Invalid Target object to be enrich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix by adding the **enrich** tag **after the payloadFactory tag** :

```
<enrich>
        <source clone="true" type="inline">
            <p857:Property propertyId="isArchived" settable="0" 
            xmlns:p857="http://www.filenet.com/ns/fnce/2006/11/ws/schema" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="p857:SingletonString">
                <p857:Value>1</p857:Value>
            </p857:Property>
        </source>
        <target action="child" xmlns:p857="http://www.filenet.com/ns/fnce/2006/11/ws/schema" 
        xpath="//p857:ExecuteChangesRequest/p857:ChangeRequest/p857:ActionProperties"/>
    </enrich>
```